# Does the induced $K^G$-comodule correspond to the induced $KG$-module?

Tags: representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group with group multiplication $m\colon G\times G \to G$ and $K$ a field. Then $K^G$ (the set-maps from $G$ to $K$) is a commutative algebra with pointwise multiplication. Because $K^\bullet$ is a contravariant functor, we get an algebra map $m^\#\colon K^G \to K^{G\times G}$. Notice that $K^G\otimes K^G$ and $K^{G\times G}$ are isomorphic by sending $\phi\otimes\psi$ to $(g,g') \mapsto \phi(g)\cdot\psi(g')$. Together with the evaluation at $1_G$, which we denote by $\epsilon\colon K^G\to K$, the algebra $K^G$ becomes a bialgebra.

There is a one-to-one correspondence between left $KG$-modules of finite dimension over $K$ and right $K^G$-comodules finite dimension over $K$. Say $V$ is a f.d. $KG$-module with basis $(v_i)$ and define $\phi_{ij}\in K^G$ by $$g\cdot v_j = \sum_i \phi_{ij}(g)v_i. $$ Then $V$ becomes a $K^G$-comodule by $\rho\colon V \to V \otimes K^G$ defined by $\rho(v_j) := \sum_i v_i\otimes \phi_{ij}$.

Let $f\colon H \to G$ be a homomorphism of finite groups and $W$ a $KH$-module. Does the induced module $\mathrm{Ind}_H^G W = KG\otimes_{KH}W$ corresond to the induced $K^G$-comodule $\ker(\rho\otimes 1 - (1\otimes f^\#\otimes 1)\circ (1\otimes m^\#) \colon W\otimes K^G \to W \otimes K^H \otimes K^G)$ of $W$ (upto isomorphism)?

**EDIT:**

First off, $KG\otimes_{KH} W$ is rather the coinduction than the induction (at least if one considers not necessarily finite dimensional algebras) and the induction is
$$ \operatorname{Hom}_{KH}(KG,W) = \{\phi\colon KG\to W\mid \phi(h\cdot g) = h\cdot \phi(g)\}.$$

Because the above "correspondence" defines a covariant functor $F$ from the category of f.d. $KG$-modules to f.d. $K^G$-comodules, by the universal property there is of course an isomorphism between $F(\operatorname{Hom}_{KH}(KG,W))$ and the induced comodule of $W$, defined above.

**My question now is**, is there a somewhat explicit way to write down this isomorphism?